How can I import only select environments?
Context
I have a multifile structure
project/
├── assignment01/
│   ├── .latekmkrc
│   └── main.tex
├── ...
├── .latexmkrc
├── exercises01.tex
└── mypreamble.tex

(The .latexmkrcs are for making sure thing link up to the mypreamble.sty properly)
Where exercises01.tex imports assignment01/main.tex like so:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{mypreamble}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}
\import{problems01/}{main}
% ...
\end{document}

and assignment01.tex has a bunch of problems (defined in mypreamble.tex):
\documentclass[class=scrartcl,
               crop=false,
               fontsize=11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mypreamble}

\begin{document}
% Problem 1
\begin{problem}
    % content
\end{problem}

% ...
\end{document}

and mypreamble.sty
\ProvidesPackage{mypreamble}
\newcounter{problem}
\NewDocumentCommand{problem}{}
    {\refstepcounter{problem}\theproblem.}

Note that I have this set up this way specifically so that I can treat each assignment as its own project and also have the exercises as a whole as something I can collect.
Question
Now, I would like to import only select problems from a few assignments, say

assignment01: Problems 1,3,5-9
assignment02: Everything
assignment04: Problem 2

Attempts
I found the comment package but honestly I'm lost by it. I tried using something like
% Problem 8
\specialcomment{problem08}{\stepcounter{problem}}{}
\begin{problem08}
\begin{problem}
    % content
\end{problem}
\end{problem08}

thinking it might step the counter regardless. But this neither steps the counter when excluding the problem nor actually works when trying to exclude from exercises01.tex.
Any help would be appreciated.

A savebox will step the counter, whether you later print it or not.  A \label will only work if you print it (but gives an error if you print it twice).  Note that it is completely formated, even when not used.
